# Растянуть изображение на весь экран в HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview

В проекте динамически получаю объекты, которые в себе содержат некие данные и пути к изображениям. Всю информацию я вывожу в `activity`, которая включает в себя корневой layout `ScrollView`. В конце этого `ScrollView` у меня лежит `HorizontalScrollView`, на который программно я кладу n-oe количество `ImageView`, таким образом:

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        for (int i = 0; i < hotel.getImages().size(); i++) {

            final int finalI = i;
            hotelImagesLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageView hotelImage = new ImageView(context);
                    hotelImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    hotelImage.setLayoutParams(params);
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(hotel.getImages().get(finalI))
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
                            .transform(transformation)
                            .into(hotelImage);
                    hotelImagesLayout.addView(hotelImage);
                }
            });


        }
```

Картинки кладуться нормально, по горизонтали тоже всё скролится ок, но! мне надо, чтобы первая картинка тянулась на весь экран, по размеру девайса, а не сохраняла свои прежние ширину и величину.

Вот разметка, куда кладу изображения:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/regionAndName"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/hotelImagesLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Как заставить тянуться изображение под ширину экрана в `horizontalScrollView`? Пробовал играться со scaleType, но чё-то не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам придется рассчитывать высоту и ширину программно.
То есть, после загрузки изображения, вам нужно задать для `ImageView` ширину и высоту, соответствующую размерам вашего экрана.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так сделать. Но мне по идее надо только ширину высчитать, а высоту уже скейлить относительно её

Comment: Да, помогло такое решение. Спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте в коде для ImageView задать ширину и высоту match_parent

Comment: так и сделал- не помогло

Comment: Хм, мой ответ по сути такой же, как у @metalurgus, но почему-то заминусили :D

Comment: Минус давал не я. Но ваши ответы никак не похожи, тем более что в вопросе я кодом показал, что программно match_parent выставлен

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @Crok, ваш ответ абсолютно не похож на мой. `match_parent` сработает только, если у парента есть определенный размер. У контейнера, который лежит в ScrollView нет конкретного размера. Попробуйте ваше решение сами, и убедитесь, что оно не работает